# PHP regex to replace whole words (in Russian html text) while ignoring the same words inside tags

Tags: php, regex

I would like to build a PHP REGEX which search for a **whole word** (that does not contain a letter from some pre defined list before it) in a string of html page written in Russian, and replace the word with a link which most of the time will include the same word inside the href attribute.
It also shouldn't replace the word if it is already inside  tag.

For example:

The Word to search and change: создать

letter list [ Я , т , со]

Html string:

```
    <div class="wiki-p">
    Яндекс и Сбербанк подписали соглашение о намерениях создать совместное предприятие на базе Яндсоздатьекс Ясоздать.
    Маркета. Объединив инфраструктуру и технологии создать
Объединив инфраструктуру и <a href="#">технологии создать </a>
    </div>
```

The output should be:

```
<div class="wiki-p">
Яндекс и Сбербанк подписали соглашение о намерениях <a href="example.com/category/создать">создать</a> совместное предприятие на базе *Яндсоздатьекс*.
Маркета. Объединив инфраструктуру и технологии <a href="example.com/category/создать">создать</a>
Объединив инфраструктуру и <a href="#">технологии создать </a>
</div>
```

The word Яндсоздатьекс, which contains the word stays unchanged,
and also Ясоздать which contains the letter Я before the word

I used the following regex:

```
$regex = '~<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|\b'. $needle . '\b~';
```

It has 3 problems:

1) It works only in English, and not in other languages

I tried to use "/u", but without success.

2) It allows the searched string to be replaced if inside a  tag:

```
Before:
<a href="#"> testes создать </a>

After:
<a href="#"> testes <a href="#">создать </a></a>
```

3) How can I check if the letter doesn't have letter from the list before it?

Beside that I read that when working with html data, it's better to work with the DOMDocument Object parser - why is it?

Comment: A regex doesn't know mark up rules the parser will. A parser will be much more accurate. The `/u` in your example should just be `u` after your closing `~`. Here's an example https://regex101.com/r/S2JiJK/1/.

Comment: You may try [`'~(?:<a\s[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>|<[^>]*>)(*SKIP)(*F)|\bсоздать\b~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/7Q1phy/1)

Comment: ... or you may not;